# SMTP sending on Yahoo and Hotmail fails

Tags: vb.net, smtp

My SMTP code works on gmail but when i try it on Yahoo and Hotmail it always fails. I have entered the correct server and port but still it won't let me send. I am really confused on where did I go wrong as I am able to perfectly send mails under gmail.

Here is my complete code:

```
Function SendEmail(ByVal Recipients As List(Of String), _
                  ByVal FromAddress As String, _
                  ByVal Subject As String, _
                  ByVal Body As String, _
                  ByVal UserName As String, _
                  ByVal Password As String, _
                  Optional ByVal Server As String, _
                  Optional ByVal Port As Integer, _
                  Optional ByVal Attachments As List(Of String) = Nothing) As String


    Dim Email As New MailMessage()
    Try
        Dim SMTPServer As New SmtpClient
        For Each Attachment As String In Attachments
            Email.Attachments.Add(New Attachment(Attachment))
        Next
        Email.From = New MailAddress(FromAddress)
        For Each Recipient As String In Recipients
            Email.To.Add(Recipient)
        Next
        Email.Subject = Subject
        Email.Body = Body
        SMTPServer.Host = Server
        SMTPServer.Port = Port
        SMTPServer.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(UserName, Password)
        SMTPServer.EnableSsl = True
        SMTPServer.Send(Email)
        SMTPServer.Timeout = 500
        Email.Dispose()

        Return "Email to " & Recipients(0) & " from " & FromAddress & " was sent."
    Catch ex As SmtpException
        Email.Dispose()
        Return "Sending Email Failed. Smtp Error."
    Catch ex As ArgumentOutOfRangeException
        Email.Dispose()
        Return "Sending Email Failed. Check Port Number."
    Catch Ex As InvalidOperationException
        Email.Dispose()
        Return "Sending Email Failed. Check Port Number."
    End Try
End Function


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim Recipients As New List(Of String)
    Recipients.Add("put recipient email here")
    Dim FromEmailAddress As String = Recipients(0)
    Dim Subject As String = "subject goes here"
    Dim Body As String = "Email body goes here"
    Dim UserName As String = "put username here"
    Dim Password As String = "put password here"
    Dim Port As Integer = port number goes here
    Dim Server As String = "SMTP server goes here"
    Dim Attachments As New List(Of String)
    MsgBox(SendEmail(Recipients, FromEmailAddress, Subject, Body, UserName, Password, Server, Port, Attachments))

End Sub
```

Does Yahoo and Hotmail behave different compared to gmail? I am really new to this SMTP thing. I have just started learning today please bear with me. Any advice or inputs will be accepted. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What ports numbers are you using for hotmail

Comment: for yahoo i used smtp.mail.yahoo.com, port 465 and hotmail smtp.live.com, port 465.

Comment: read my answer, you have information for both servers. Use EnableSSl on both. They use 587 and 995

Answer (score 0):

They work on different port:

> Hotmail Outgoing Mail Server (SMTP) - smtp.live.com (TLS enabled, port 587)
>
> Yahoo Outgoing Mail Server (SMTP) - smtp.mail.yahoo.com (SSL enabled, port 995)

Be sure you are using :

```
SMTPServer.EnableSsl = True
```

And **changing the SMTP port for each service**. (In this case, 587 for Hotmail).

One is SSL and the other one is TLS. TLS (Transport Level Security) is the slightly broader term that has replaced SSL so dont worry, it will work using `EnableSsl`

Comment: it is being catched by the exception i have created:

   Catch ex As SmtpException
        Email.Dispose()
        Return "Sending Email Failed. Smtp Error."

Comment: Yeah thats correct. The port you are using must be wrong. Change port number according to the smtp address of the destination server. if you use  smtp.live.com address, port is 587, and if you use smtp.mail.yahoo.com port is 995

Comment: already replaced those ports with the one you gave me but still gives me the smtpexception. on gmail i had no problems like this.

Comment: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.3.4 Requested action not taken; We noticed some unusual activity in your Hotmail account. To help protect you, we've temporarily blocked your account. < this one, but this is a new account i have created, i had never sent a single mail using this.

Comment: Ok, you have bein performing illegal actions, like logging with incorrect password or attacking wrong port using programming. Account must have been locked. Log into hotmail website and take needed action. Maybe you need to re active account

Answer (score 0):

You could use `EASendMail` library for .NET, it automatically detect ports.

http://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail/

Example I did:

```
   Private Function Hotmail_Sender(ByVal Account_User As String, ByVal Account_Password As String, ByVal Mail_To As String, ByVal Mail_Subject As String, ByVal Mail_Body As String, Optional ByVal Mail_Attachments() As String = Nothing) As Boolean

       Dim Hot_Mail As New EASendMail.SmtpMail("TryIt")
       Dim Hot_Server As New EASendMail.SmtpServer("smtp.live.com")
       Dim Hot_Smtp As New EASendMail.SmtpClient()

       Hot_Server.User = Account_User
       Hot_Server.Password = Account_Password
       Hot_Server.ConnectType = EASendMail.SmtpConnectType.ConnectSSLAuto

       Hot_Mail.From = Account_User
       Hot_Mail.To = Mail_To
       Hot_Mail.Subject = Mail_Subject
       Hot_Mail.TextBody = Mail_Body
       If Mail_Attachments IsNot Nothing Then For Each Attachment In Mail_Attachments : Hot_Mail.AddAttachment(Attachment) : Next

       Try : Hot_Smtp.SendMail(Hot_Server, Hot_Mail) : Return True
       Catch ex As Exception : Return False : End Try

   End Function
```

Comment: No need to use third party assemblies to send a simple email. Just use their server information.

Comment: The library has more beneffits than what I've commented. and its the best if don't want to waste time updating the ports of all smtp servers